# active GPU rendering in Blender

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have ubuntu studio, I want to active GPU rendeing in Blender, 
I have a AMD Radeon R7 240 and it works fine when I play games so I don't think it's a drivers problem,it's  even on the list of the supported cards in blender... but still in the user preferences, in the compute device I can only select CPU and in the rendering option instead of the GPU option I have "Experimental" with danger sign ...

Why?

Comment: it could depend on the drivers, afaik. I guess newer proprietary ones are your bet chance.

Comment: maybe .. but then why it works with games? isn't it strange?

Comment: which blender version and amd drivers are you running on US? Anyway you could open a bugtracker issue... amd support is young.

Comment: the last version...I have read some cases of drivers incompatible with the last kernel updates for AMD ...I hope that's not my problem